# Audit.Net: add customfields

Tags: audit.net

I am new to the use of audit.net.
I need to audit a series of custom values from the parameters received in the action method as follows.

```
[AuditField("User","reqLogin.User")]              
[AuditCustom(EventTypeName =  "AccesoAction")]  
public async Task<IActionResult> Acceso(LoginRequest reqLogin)
{            
     ...
}
```

I have to create a CustomField with FieldName "User" and value, the value of the User attribute of parameter reqLogin (reqLogin.User).

I'm extending the AuditAttribute class, to overwrite the OnActionExecutionAsync method and add the CustomField.

```
public class AuditCustomAttribute : AuditAttribute
{
  public override Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
  {
      lock (context.ActionDescriptor.Parameters)
      {
        foreach (AuditFieldAttribute apa in context.ActionDescriptor.Parameters.Cast<ControllerParameterDescriptor>().First().ParameterInfo.Member.GetCustomAttributes<AuditFieldAttribute>())
    {
           // create CustomField and add to context
    }
}   
 return base.OnActionExecutionAsync(context, next);
}
}
```

Finally, in my custom AuditDataProvider class, I would audit the customFields that arrived in the auditevent field   of method:

```
  public override object InsertEvent(AuditEvent auditEvent)
```

How would it be possible?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's not very clear what are you asking, but I guess you're using the [Audit.MVC](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET/blob/master/src/Audit.Mvc/README.md) extension.

Why do you need to create a CustomField with information you already have on the [ActionParameters](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET/blob/master/src/Audit.Mvc/AuditAttribute.cs#L81)?

Also I don't think you need to subclass the `AuditAttribute` being that there is already a [CustomAction](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET#custom-actions) mechanism you can use, for example:

```
Audit.Core.Configuration.AddOnCreatedAction(scope =>
{
    var action = scope.GetMvcAuditAction();
    var login = action.ActionParameters.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Key == "reqLogin").Value as LoginRequest;
    scope.SetCustomField("User", login.User);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, I'm using Audit.MVC. Using scope.SetCustomField in Action is a possibility to solve the problem but, it is possible to overwrite OnActionExecutionAsync to add custom parameters that can intercept in a AuditDataProvider custom class?

Comment: Yes you can. But I guess the problem to solve for your approach would be to translate the string `"reqLogin.User"` into the property value of `reqLogin.User`

Comment: Hi. By reflection I can obtain the values of the parameters. That is already solved, it was just an example.  Is correct to use Audit.Core.Configuration.AddOnCreatedAction(scope =>...) in the method OnActionExecutionAsync? Thanks so much for the help

Comment: No it is not correct. The `AddOnCreatedAction` should be called just once, i.e. on your startup code

Comment: ok, then, what is the best way to add custom field in the method OnActionExecutionAsync?. I'm seeing how customfield is added from the controller's Action method and from the method OnActionExecutionAsync, in the same scope. Thanks

Comment: You can get current scope with `AuditAttribute.GetCurrentScope(httpContext);`, but since the AuditScope is created, saved and disposed within the OnActionExecutionAsync, you will not be able to add custom fields there to be persisted. What do you need from the ActionExecutingContext that is not on the audit event?

Comment: Hi. My main problem is that I have to allow customfield to be added with information about certain parameters of an Action method of the controller.
I have to add this information from an ActionFilterAttribute class, applying reflection to the parameters of the Action method because I can not do it by adding code within the action method (such as auditScope.SetCustomField (..)) for this type of information

Comment: I also have to allow other customfields to be added as the result of performing the operation (incorrect 0, error produced, 1 correct execution) or any other parameter, in this case, adding code within the action method of the controller, as indicated in the examples.  Now I am testing the following:                        
    var controller = context.Controller as Controller;
            var scope = controller .GetCurrentAuditScope();, but in OnResultExecutionAsync (...)

Comment: So it looks like `AddOnCreatedAction`/`AddOnSavingAction` fits your needs. You can access the parameters and result there, to add any custom field you want.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help, I will try to use the event AddOnSavingAction. Thanks a lots